# abnormal behavior of the kernel jbd2 process

Tags: linux, ext4

I want to understand the mechanism of the journal of the ext4 file system on partitions with no free space. When a process (apache-tomcat, in my case) keeps making small additions to debug log files, after some time disk partitions run out of space. By itself this situation is not bad. But at this point, the abnormal behavior of the kernel's `jbd2` process begins. The tool `iotop` shows that the process consumes 100% of IO. Looking at the storage system, I see increased write activity to a disk that does not have space for these writes.

Comment: The scenario described above is reproduced on the operating system redhat 6.x (3<=x<=6).